# Google Analytics Page Load Times vs Pingdom Page Load Times.

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, pingdom

I am examining the page load time numbers in GA and Pingdom. My avg via pingdom is consistently 3 seconds, or around that. My page load time in GA is consistently around 10 seconds. Can anyone explain the technical reason for this difference. Please.

Any Reference to this information would be helpful, I haven't been able to find a straight answer.

Comment: Are you sure they're both measuring the length of time to download assets like CSS, JS, images, etc.?

Comment: at the risk of answering my own question, my assumption is that pingdom is measuring the time to receive the html doc ... the time to doc.ready. While GA is measuring time to last bite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, and you've probably moved on, but Pingdom only tests the response time from the server (how long it takes the server to return a 200, 4XX or 5XX status), not even the time to receive the HTML doc; while Google Analytics shows the load time of the entire page, including all content and every asset loaded.